Join 2 dataframes and fill values in place of null
I am looking for ways to join 2 dataframes and also fill in values in places where values are not available.
In this example, I have 1st dataframe input1 that has data for all the fields. I am trying to use this dataframe and fill/join with 2nd dataframe input2 and produce output dataframe.
row1 in dataframe1 can be joined with row2 by matching Age columns and filling Name column.
row2 in dataframe1 can be joined with row2 by filling Name and Age columns from dataframe1.
row1 in dataframe1 can also be joined with row2 by filling Name and Age columns from dataframe1.
   Name  Age  Courses
0   Tom   20     Math
1  Nick   21  Science

   Name   Age  Fees
0   NaN  20.0   100
1   NaN   NaN   200

   Name  Age  Courses  Fees
0   Tom   20     Math   100
1  Nick   21  Science   200
2   Tom   20     Math   200


input1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick'],
    'Age': [20, 21],
    'Courses': ['Math', 'Science']
})

input2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': [np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'Age': [20, np.NaN],
    'Fees': [100, 200]
})

output = pd.DataFrame({
  'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick', 'Tom'],
  'Age': [20, 21, 20],
  'Courses': ['Math', 'Science', 'Math'],
  'Fees': [100, 200, 200]
})


Code
One possible approach is to use pandas merge function to create a cartesian product with cross join, and then filter only the rows that meet the condition (note that cross join is inefficient if the data is very large).
# Define columns to be compared to variable cols.
cols = ['Name', 'Age']

# Perform a cross join between input1 and input2
tmp = input1.merge(input2, how='cross', suffixes=['', '_y'])

# Filter out the columns which have the '_y' suffix
tmp2 = tmp.filter(like='_y').set_axis(cols, axis=1)

# Create condition
cond = (tmp[cols].eq(tmp2) | tmp2.isna()).all(axis=1)

# filter
out = tmp.loc[cond, tmp.columns[~tmp.columns.str.contains('_y')]]

out
    Name    Age Courses Fees
0   Tom     20  Math    100
1   Tom     20  Math    200
3   Nick    21  Science 200

